# LESS Interpolar string not parsed

Tags: less

I have a simple interpolar string that does not get parsed. It works when i use lessPHP but not when i use the lesscss js.

```
li.nl a{background:url(/@{localImages}/icons/flags/gif/nl.gif) no-repeat center center;}
```

Variable:

```
@localImages:               "../images/local/";
```

The return:

```
.topbar #block-locale-language li.nl a {
    background: url("/@{localImages}/icons/flags/gif/nl.gif") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to this...

```
background:url(~"@{localImages}icons/flags/gif/nl.gif") no-repeat center center;
```

Which produces this:

```
background: url(../images/local/icons/flags/gif/nl.gif) no-repeat center center;
```